# Facebook query result is string of hashes

Tags: ruby, json, facebook, hash

I'm using the koala gem to query Facebook.
The following query yields a string? of hashes. For example:

```
@graph.get_object("search?q=holden&type=page&limit=5")
```

When I say string of hashes, the result looks something like this:

```
{"name"=>"Holden", "category"=>"Cars", "id"=>"5730024897"}
{"name"=>"Holden, Massachusetts", "category"=>"City", "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"224455390913969", "name"=>"City"}], "id"=>"104015212968818"}
{"name"=>"Holden, Maine", "category"=>"City", "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"224455390913969", "name"=>"City"}], "id"=>"112517345426169"}
{"name"=>"Holden, Missouri", "category"=>"City", "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"224455390913969", "name"=>"City"}], "id"=>"107921245894576"}
{"name"=>"Holden, Louisiana", "category"=>"City", "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"224455390913969", "name"=>"City"}], "id"=>"111960155481686"}
```

There are no commas between the hashes, and of course, some of the values are themselves hashes.

Trying to do `JSON.parse` as it is gives a JSON error, as it is not well formed JSON.
So I think I can parse this by just keeping track of opening and closing braces, but before I reinvent the wheel, and probably a clunky one at that, I was wondering if there was some cool ruby way of doing this. Can I somehow chomp a hash? or...?

Looking forward to being dazzled!

Comment: can you post the exact "string of hashes" it returns?

Comment: @Juan Manuel Rodulfo Salcedo - I edited the question to show some real FB output. However, I'm not really after a brute force way to read this, as it's not that difficult. I was really only wandering if there's a clever Ruby one-liner?

Comment: The API does return valid JSON (which you can easily confirm, by calling `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=holden&type=page&limit=5&access_token={add_a_valid_token_here}` directly in your browser. The name of the method you are using is `get_object` – so I would assume that it does return an object already; meaning, a ruby data structure of some sort. You probably just got fooled by whatever method you used to make that debug output(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know a better way of doing so much transformations in a fancy way..

If your string is like i copied it from the code:

```
[68] pry(main)> string
=> "{\"name\"=>\"Holden\", \"category\"=>\"Cars\", \"id\"=>\"5730024897\"}\n{\"name\"=>\"Holden, Massachusetts\", \"category\"=>\"City\", \"category_list\"=>[{\"id\"=>\"224455390913969\", \"name\"=>\"City\"}], \"id\"=>\"104015212968818\"}\n{\"name\"=>\"Holden, Maine\", \"category\"=>\"City\", \"category_list\"=>[{\"id\"=>\"224455390913969\", \"name\"=>\"City\"}], \"id\"=>\"112517345426169\"}\n{\"name\"=>\"Holden, Missouri\", \"category\"=>\"City\", \"category_list\"=>[{\"id\"=>\"224455390913969\", \"name\"=>\"City\"}], \"id\"=>\"107921245894576\"}\n{\"name\"=>\"Holden, Louisiana\", \"category\"=>\"City\", \"category_list\"=>[{\"id\"=>\"224455390913969\", \"name\"=>\"City\"}], \"id\"=>\"111960155481686\"}"

[69] pry(main)> string.split("\n").map { |a| JSON.parse(a.gsub("=>",":")) }
=> [{"name"=>"Holden", "category"=>"Cars", "id"=>"5730024897"},
 {"name"=>"Holden, Massachusetts",
  "category"=>"City",
  "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"224455390913969", "name"=>"City"}],
  "id"=>"104015212968818"},
 {"name"=>"Holden, Maine",
  "category"=>"City",
  "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"224455390913969", "name"=>"City"}],
  "id"=>"112517345426169"},
 {"name"=>"Holden, Missouri",
  "category"=>"City",
  "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"224455390913969", "name"=>"City"}],
  "id"=>"107921245894576"},
 {"name"=>"Holden, Louisiana",
  "category"=>"City",
  "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"224455390913969", "name"=>"City"}],
  "id"=>"111960155481686"}]
```

if it is all in the same string line (without "\n")

```
string.gsub('}{','},,{').split(",,").map { |a| JSON.parse(a.gsub("=>",":")) }
```

Comment: This is where is should have looked! https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API
It seems the response is already an array of hashes and I can use that.
Not JSON at all. Thanks Juan,